# split now complains about missing "isSeparator"

Tags: swift

After the latest upgrade of Swift 1.2, I can't figure out how to split a line of text into words. I used to do this:

```
let bits = split(value!, { $0 == " "}, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)
```

But that no longer works, because...

```
Cannot invoke 'split' with an argument list of type '(String, (_) -> _, maxSplit: Int, allowEmptySlices: Bool)'
```

Ummm, ok, even though I could last build? Well whatever, let's try...

```
let bits = split(value!, { $0 == " "})
```

Well that and every other version I can think of ends up saying:

```
Missing argument for parameter 'isSeparator' in call
```

Let's hear it for beta-testing new programming languages! Yay!

Anyone know the correct secret sauce for 1.2?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that the order of the parameters changed in Swift 1.2:

```
let bits = split(value!, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false,
                 isSeparator: { $0 == " "})
```

or, using the default values:

```
let bits = split(value!, isSeparator: { $0 == " "})
```

The predicate is now the last parameter and requires an external
parameter name `isSeparator` because it is preceded by optional parameters.

The advantage of this change is that you can use the *trailing closure
syntax*:

```
let bits = split(value!, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false) { $0 == " " }
```

or

```
let bits = split(value!) { $0 == " " }
```

Comment: LOLZ. Thanks Apple. And non-sarcastic thanks to Martin, this does indeed fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks Apple. It's possible the change in the split function caused a particularly nasty bug I experienced with a Release mode build (see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107277/swift-release-build-crashes-unless-i-turn-off-optimization/32361548#32361548).