# Split a string into an Array in Swift

Tags: string, swift, split

I'm trying to write my first Swift program, and I know this question has been asked before, but the answers using split aren't working for me.  I'm using Xcode 6.4 and Swift 1.2.

I have a String named line.

If I write

```
 let inputs = split(line) {$0 = " "}
```

as suggested at [Swift: Split a String into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array), I get the error message "Cannot invoke 'split' with an argument list of type (String, (*)->*)"

If I write

```
let inputs = split(line, {find(" ",$0)  != nil}, allowEmptySlices: false)
```

as suggested at [split now complains about missing "isSeparator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726774/split-now-complains-about-missing-isseparator), I get the error message, "Missing argument for parameter 'isSeparator' in call."

If I jump to the definition of split, I find

```
func split<S : Sliceable, R : BooleanType>(elements: S, maxSplit: Int = default, allowEmptySlices: Bool = default, #isSeparator: @noescape (S.Generator.Element) -> R) -> [S.SubSlice]
```

I don't understand what the type of the last parameter is, which is perhaps the root of my problem.  Can you tell me how I should call split, and even better can you explain what the parameter type is?  Why isn't the type simply (S)->R?  I am getting the line from a generator that reads a file line-by-line, if that makes any difference.

```
for line:String in reader! {
 let inputs = split(line) {$0 = " "}
 ...
}
```

Comment: `let inputs = split(line) {$0 == " "} `

Comment: Comparison is done with `==`. `=` is an assignment operator.

Comment: It's hard to believe I looked at the code so many times, but overlooked that.  I feel so stupid,  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments to the question, the correct way is to use the `==` operator instead of `=`.

The type `(S.Generator.Element) -> R)` must be interpreted in the light of the definition of `split`:

```
func split<S : Sliceable, R : BooleanType>
  (elements: S, 
   maxSplit: Int = default, 
   allowEmptySlices: Bool = default, 
   #isSeparator: @noescape (S.Generator.Element) -> R) 
      -> [S.SubSlice]
```

The type of `split` is a generic one: in other words, it is a function that can take as first parameter any value that satisfy a generic type (or protocol) subtype of `Sliceable`, like `String`, and return a result which must be a subtype of `BooleanType` (for instance `true` or `false`, which are instances of Bool). So the last parameter is a function which gets as parameter a type which is `Element` of `Generator` of `S` (for instance `Character`) and returns a value of type `R`. And `{$0 == " "}` is exactly a predicate of this type, that has an (implicit) parameter (`$0`), and check if it is equal to the character `" "`.

Comment: A very lucid explanation, thank you.  I was thinking of "generator" in the python sense.   Can you please point me to where I can read more about the technicalities?

Comment: There are many introductory [resources](https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/) on the Apple web site, for instance the video on [Advanced Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=404). The advanced type system of Swift, however, is based on type technologies that were studied in the middle of '80s. One of the best technical papers, which is readable with a little effort, is the seminal [On Understanding Types,
Data Abstraction, and Polymorphism](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/OnUnderstanding.pdf) by L. Cardelli and P. Wegner.