# Cannot invoke 'split' with an argument list of type '(String, (String) -> Bool)'. Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I am currently facing the following problem with a program that I am using to learn Swift and OAuth with: https://github.com/soundcloud/iOSOAuthDemo.

The error is as follows:

> Cannot invoke 'split' with an argument list of type '(String, (String) -> Bool)'

with this snippet:

```
private func parameterValue(name: String, fragment: String) -> String? {
    let pairs = split(fragment) { $0 == "&" }.filter({ pair in pair.hasPrefix(name + "=") })
    if pairs.count > 0 {
        return split(pairs[0]) { $0 == "=" }[1]
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The guidance is:

> Expected an argument list of type '(S, maxSplit: Int, allowEmptySlices: Bool, isSeparator: @noescape (S.Generator.Element) -> R)'

Is there anyone who may be help me to remove this error, as I am new to Swift and Swift 2.0?

Thanks In Advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift version of componentsSeparatedByString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226940/swift-version-of-componentsseparatedbystring)

Comment: Have a look, the title has nothing to do with your question but the accepted answer contains what you need.

Comment: changing: `private func parameterValue(name: String, fragment: String) -> String? {
        let pairs = split(fragment) { $0 == "&" }.filter({ pair in pair.hasPrefix(name + "=") })
        if pairs.count > 0 {
            return split(pairs[0]) { $0 == "=" }[1]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }` to  `let str = pairs
let arr = split(str, { $0 == " "}, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)` doesnt seem to have worked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The main idea with this duplicate link was to show you that in Swift 2 String is not a collection anymore, you have to use the String's `characters` property (and `split` is not a global function anymore). You also have to make some types back to String. Example:

```
private func parameterValue(name: String, fragment: String) -> String? {
    let pairs = fragment.characters.split { $0 == "&" }.filter({ pair in String(pair).hasPrefix(name + "=") })
    if pairs.count > 0 {
        let subseq = pairs[0].split { $0 == "=" }.map { String($0) }
        return subseq[1]
    }
    return nil
}

parameterValue("mike", fragment: "&mike=test")  // "test"
```

Note that instead you could use the String's `componentsSeparatedByString` method to make your function look a bit simpler:

```
private func parameterValue(name: String, fragment: String) -> String? {
    let pairs = fragment.componentsSeparatedByString("&").filter { $0.hasPrefix(name + "=") }
    if !pairs.isEmpty {
        return pairs[0].componentsSeparatedByString("=")[1]
    }
    return nil
}

parameterValue("mike", fragment: "&mike=test")  // "test"
```

Comment: Great. This has really helped Eric D.