# Swift filter map reduce which option

Tags: swift, algorithm

I have quick question about Swift algorithm, assuming I have a string “New Message” which option I need to use to get just initials NM ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285978/get-the-initials-from-a-name-and-limit-it-to-2-initials https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540332/how-to-get-the-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-string

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `map` to get the first character of each word in the string, then use `reduce` to combine them.

```
let string = "New Message"
let individualWords = string.components(separatedBy: " ")
let firstCharacters = individualWords.map { $0.prefix(1) }.reduce("", +)
print("firstCharacters is \(firstCharacters)")
```

Result:

> firstCharacters is NM

**Edit:** Per @LeoDabus' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386821/swift-filter-map-reduce-which-option/67386916#comment119108964_67386916), `joined` is more concise than `reduce("", +)`, and does the same thing.

```
let firstCharacters = individualWords.map { $0.prefix(1) }.joined()
```

Comment: `.reduce("", +)`  ?? Why not simply `.joined()`
 ?

Comment: @LeoDabus ah yeah that would be better

Comment: in the first approach you can get rid of the map when reducing your string `.reduce("") { $0 + $1.prefix(1) }`