# Split characters migrate from swift 2 to 3

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift3

I converted my project to swift 3, but stuck on following sequence. How to convert `split` function to swift 3.

```
    let myString = " key=value "

    let myData = myString.characters.split(1, allowEmptySlices: true, isSeparator: { $0 == "=" }).map(String.init)

    if let postValue = (valueWithData.count > 1 ? valueWithData[1] : nil) as String? {
       postData += "\(valueWithData[0])=\(postValue)&"                      
     }
```

I need get key value from `myString`. Got error:

> 'split(_:allowEmptySlices:isSeparator:)' has been explicitly marked
>   unavailable here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226940/swift-version-of-componentsseparatedbystring has code for Swift 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: You can also type `myString.characters.split` in Xcode and see all available completions ...

Comment: In a playground you get a more enlightening error message: `error: 'split(_:allowEmptySlices:isSeparator:)' is unavailable: call 'split(maxSplits:omittingEmptySubsequences:whereSeparator:)' and invert the 'allowEmptySlices' argument`

Comment: allowEmptySlices is not allow now, but what to do...